# Select a matching string randomly from a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, random, windows-phone-8

Say I have `List<string> FontStyle` containing the following

```
        "a0.png",
        "b0.png",
        "b1.png",
        "b2.png",
        "b3.png", 
        "c0.png",
        "c1.png",
        "d0.png",
        "d1.png",
        "d2.png"
```

I want to randomly select a string from the list with its first character matches a certain character. For example if the character is `c`. The method will returns either `c0.png` or `c1.png` randomly.

How do I do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var random = new Random();
var list = new List<string> {
    "a0.png",
    "b0.png",
    "b1.png",
    "b2.png",
    "b3.png", 
    "c0.png",
    "c1.png",
    "d0.png",
    "d1.png",
    "d2.png" 
};
var startingChar = "d";

var filteredList = list.Where(s => s.StartsWith(startingChar)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(filteredList.Count);

int index = random.Next(filteredList.Count);
Console.WriteLine(index);

var font = filteredList[index];
Console.WriteLine(font);
```

but the problem with the entire solution is that the smaller the resulting filtered list is the less likely you are to get really random values. The `Random` class works much better on much larger constraints - so just keep that in mind.

Comment: sorry, but probably you meant `Where` instead of `Select` in the first line

Comment: Last line won't compile - filteredList is not a list, it's an `IEnumerable<T>`. Needs `ToList()` on the first line.

Comment: @KentBoogaart, thanks a lot. I need to get it setup so I can build these little examples in Notepad++ and compile them there. Doesn't Jon Skeet do that?

Comment: @Michael: I'm thinking ScriptCS will be perfect for that. Skeet compiles in his head in less time than the C# compiler takes.

Comment: @KentBoogaart, thanks a lot for that, I got it installed and rebuilt this example compiled in `ScriptCs`. Absolutely fantastic!

Comment: @Michael: yeah, rub it in ;) I can't run it because I'm on XP (corporate environment) which doesn't support .NET 4.5 :( Soon....soon!

Answer (score 4):

```
Random random = ...;
var itemsStartingWithC = input
    .Where(x => x.StartsWith("c"))
    .ToList();
var randomItemStartingWithC =
    itemsStartingWithC.ElementAt(random.Next(0, itemsStartingWithC.Count()));
```

The call to `ToList` isn't strictly necessary, but results in faster code in this instance. Without it, `Count()` will fully enumerate and `ElementAt` will need to enumerate to the randomly selected index.

Comment: wont this select random `char` from each string, that start from `c`?

Comment: @Ilya: you're right - I meant `ElementAt` but typed `Select`. Corrected.

Comment: ElementAt cannot take `func`

Comment: yes, but this is not quite right. `x.Count` will return the length of the substring, while you are using it inside `ElementAt`. You need to access `Count` on a filtered list